# Rails - How to use Devise in both API and non-API mode in the same application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

`rails 7.0.3.1`

`devise 4.8.1`

I'm aware that its possible to use [Devise in API mode](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/API-Mode-Compatibility-Guide). But is it possible to use Devise both in API and non-API mode, "at the same time"? One use case of this is having one Rails app both serving its own static pages and being a back-end to a front-end client (e.g. developed using React).

Answer (score 2):

I have just built an application like this and your key challenge is Devise uses a cookie to authenticate in Rails static web pages but needs to use a token or JWT to authenticate on the API. Getting it to do both in 1 app can be a bit of a challenge. Here is how I solved it, very open to other / better ideas as the below works but I feel it's a little hacky:

In routes I have this (simplified):

```
devise_for :users

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_scope :user do
        post "sign_up", to: "registrations#create"
        post "sign_in", to: "sessions#create"
        post "update/:id", to: "users#update"
      end
    end
  end
  root to: "pages#home"
```

This allows me to have both the default devise controller in the rails static pages and a devise mode for the API too.

In my application controller I am using authorising user for all actions and using pundit white list approach like this, it doesn't have to be this way, could be set up any number of ways:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  include Pundit

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # Pundit: white-list approach.
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index, unless: :skip_pundit?

  protected

  def skip_pundit?
    devise_controller? || params[:controller] =~ /(^(rails_)?admin)|(^pages$)/
  end

end
```

The above + standard login views generated by devise on `rails generate devise:install` cover my static page needs.

Then in the API there are some challenges.

I am using simple_token_auth gem - there are specific reasons for this and the particular app has a very low value to an account but I would probably recommend using a JWT either way: sessions and registrations work fine handled by their specific controllers which inherit from devise:

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    # sign up
    def create
      user = User.new user_params
      if user.save
        render json: {
          messages: "Sign Up Successfully",
          is_success: true,
          data: { user: user }
        }, status: :ok
      else
        render json: {
          messages: "Sign Up Failed",
          is_success: false,
          data: {}
        }, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, etc.)
    end
  end
```

sessions:

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :sign_in_params, only: :create
  before_action :load_user, only: :create
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
  # sign in
  def create
    if @user.valid_password?(sign_in_params[:password])
      sign_in "user", @user
      render json: {
        messages: "Signed In Successfully",
        is_success: true,
        data: {user: @user}
      }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {
        messages: "Signed In Failed - Unauthorized",
        is_success: false,
        data: {}
      }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def sign_in_params
    params.require(:sign_in).permit :email, :password
  end

  def load_user
    @user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: sign_in_params[:email])
    if @user
      return @user
    else
      render json: {
        messages: "Cannot get User",
        is_success: false,
        data: {}
      }, status: :failure
    end
  end
end
```

The challenge I found was with editing. I had to create a specific controller that did not inherit from devise but from the api V1 base_controller (which itself inherits from ActionController::API) to do this, it ended up looking like:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    if user.valid_password?(params[:current_password].to_s)
      puts 'password matched'
      user.update(user_params)
      render json: {
          messages: "Updated Successfully",
          is_success: true,
          data: {user: user}
        }, status: 201
    else
      puts 'pw didnt match'
      render json: {
          messages: "Incorrect Password Please Try Again",
          is_success: false,
          data: {user: user}
        }, status: 403
    end
  end

    private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, etc.)
    end
end
```

This works but the security on the update path is questionable due to the simple_user_auth tokens being what they are. I've mitigated this in a few places but don't recommend copy/pasting for a production application. Use JWTs.

On the user model you also need the following:

```
acts_as_token_authenticatable
devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

I am not sure why inheriting from devise wouldn't work for the update path, but I spent 2 days on it before giving up and writing my own.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but i'm sure you will get other answers that will give more detailed answers. I think you can acheive what you want, with defining extra routes and extra set up.
I would ask myself is there any benefit of having rails views AND a seperate react app? Cant the same result be achieved by using only react frontend and a rails api?
There are some good tutorials by Deanin on YouTube describing a lot of react integration with rails. I have a rails app that has rails views which expose an Api to a React app, and this works well but the authentications are handled seperately for each app as I dont need it to be the same app doing this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).